# Why is a Variable declared as NVARCHAR(MAX) dropping chunks of the string?

Tags: sql-server, max, nvarchar

For whatever reason, a query is being built as a string and passed off to be executed by another stored procedure.

The query is massive.

Over a thousand lines, and we've run into an issue that requires me to debug it.

The query is being built into a declared `NVARCHAR(MAX)` variable, but something odd is happening when I print it off using the following -

```
WHILE @Printed < @ToPrint BEGIN 
    PRINT(SUBSTRING(
        @sql, @Printed, 4000))
    SET @Printed = @Printed + 4000
    PRINT('Printed: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Printed))
END
```

At a certain place in the printed message, it's just... dropping a chunk, and I don't understand why. `NVARCHAR(MAX)` should be able to hold War and Peace over 100 times, and this query is NOT War and Peace.

I know `PRINT(...)` has a limitation of only being able to print off 4000 characters at a time (hence the loop), but that doesn't explain why the `@sql` variable is just losing a chunk in places.

If it helps, specifically, the place where the chunk is dropping is about 1,600 characters after the first 4,000 characters are printed.

Why is it doing this? Am I missing setting a system variable at the start of the query (like NOCOUNT or ARITHABORT? I don't even know what those do, or if they're even involved.

---

EDIT : MCVE : [Here.](https://pastebin.com/dLqvSV14) To reproduce, copy-paste into Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and hit 'F5'. The message printed will not include @sql in its entirety.

Comment: What does `SELECT DATALENGTH(@sql);` yield? What happens if you consume the output from an application instead of relying on wonky, limited print output in a GUI? (In other words, I think how you're evaluating the output is the problem, not the variable.)

Comment: Why do you need to `PRINT` the entirety of the variable anyway (which I assume contains a dynamic statement/batch)? Generally the only time you would need to do that is if you are debugging the statement; and then you would likely be better off targetting the specific part of the (dynamic) batch that's failing; which likely won't be 4,000+ characters long.

Comment: Or, if possible, [convert the thing to XML](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3185/validate-the-contents-of-large-dynamic-sql-strings-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).

Comment: @Larnu - I am debugging the statement. For the moment, I'm just trying to see what statement the query is generating so I can see why it's failing.
@AaronBertrand - The unedited query, once built, is 27,086 characters (I'm guessing, it's what's returned by the suggested `SELECT` statement.

Comment: As Aaron has shown in his answer, your code example works as intended, so the error is somewhere else. Please provide a [mcve] (for example, on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)), and we will be glad to help you find the error.

Comment: @Heinzi - MCVE Example, and subset of output set provided.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: When you come back to add more information to the question, please do focus on _how you're building the string_ and not _how you're "proving" that it is not rendering correctly_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is working fine for me:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 
    REPLICATE(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N'a'), 4000)
  + REPLICATE(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N'b'), 4000)
  + REPLICATE(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N'c'), 4000)
  + REPLICATE(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N'd'), 4000)
  + REPLICATE(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N'e'), 4000)
  + REPLICATE(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N'f'), 4000)
  + REPLICATE(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N'g'), 4000)
  + REPLICATE(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N'h'), 4000)
  + REPLICATE(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N'i'), 4000);


PRINT LEN(@sql);  -- characters
PRINT DATALENGTH(@sql); -- bytes
PRINT '';

DECLARE @Printed int = 1, @ToPrint int = LEN(@sql);

WHILE @Printed < @ToPrint BEGIN 
    PRINT(SUBSTRING(
        @sql, @Printed, 4000))
    SET @Printed = @Printed + 4000
    PRINT('Printed: ' + CONVERT(varchar(11), @Printed)) -- *
END
```

** [Always specify length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).*

Output is:

```
36000
72000

aaaaaaaaaa... 4000 As ...aaa
Printed: 4001
bbbbbbbbbb... 4000 Bs ...bbb
Printed: 8001
cccccccccc... 4000 Cs ...ccc
Printed: 12001
dddddddddd... 4000 Ds ...ddd
Printed: 16001
eeeeeeeeee... 4000 Es ...eee
Printed: 20001
ffffffffff... 4000 Cs ...fff
Printed: 24001
gggggggggg... 4000 As ...ggg
Printed: 28001
hhhhhhhhhh... 4000 Bs ...hhh
Printed: 32001
iiiiiiiiii... 4000 Cs ...iii
Printed: 36001
```

So, I think the problem is elsewhere. In any case, this is a really sloppy way to validate the contents of dynamic SQL. Instead I would do:

```
SELECT CONVERT(xml, @sql);
```

Then you can click on the output cell and it opens in an XML text editor for review (you can then copy and paste that output into a query window if you want IntelliSense or any chance in executing, but you'll have to replace encoded characters like `&gt;` --> `>`. I talk about this approach (and another one) here:

- [Validate the contents of large dynamic SQL strings](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3185/validate-the-contents-of-large-dynamic-sql-strings-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

If you insist on doing it this bricklaying way, perhaps there is some kind of non-printing or string-termination character that's at that point. If you say it is around character 5,600 then you could do:

```
DECLARE @i int = 5550, @c nchar(1);
WHILE @i <= 5650
BEGIN
  PRINT '';
  SET @c = SUBSTRING(@sql, @i, 1);
  PRINT '------   ' + RTRIM(@i) + '------:';
  PRINT 'Raw:     ' + @c;
  PRINT 'ASCII:   ' + ASCII(@c);
  PRINT 'UNICODE: ' + UNICODE(@c);
  SET @i += 1;
END
```

You should be able to scan down and match the last sequence of characters you see in the broken print output. Then look for anything where the `Raw:` line is empty and the `ASCII:` line is anything other than typical (`9`, `10`, `13`, `32`).

But I don't think this is the problem. I'll go back to an earlier comment where I suggested that the string itself is the problem. In the question, you mention `@sql`, but don't show how it's populated. I would bet that some string you're adding to that is getting truncated. Some things to look out for:

- Intermediate variables/parameters declared as `varchar`/`nvarchar` but with no length (which [sometimes leads to *silent* truncation at 1 character, and sometimes 30](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)):

  ```
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.table ';
    DECLARE @where nvarchar = N'WHERE some condition...';
    SET @sql += @where;
    PRINT @sql;
  ```

  Output:

  ```
    SELECT * FROM dbo.table W
  ```
- Intermediate variables/parameters declared as `varchar`/`nvarchar` but too short (which leads to *silent* truncation at whatever the declaration is):

  ```
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.table ';
    DECLARE @where nvarchar(10) = N'WHERE some condition...';
    SET @sql += @where;
    PRINT @sql;
  ```

  Output:

  ```
    SELECT * FROM dbo.table WHERE some
  ```
- Explicit `CONCAT` with `NULL`, which leads to *silently* dropping any `NULL` input):

  ```
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.table ';
    DECLARE @where nvarchar(32);
    DECLARE @orderby nvarchar(32) = N' ORDER BY col1';
    SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql, @where, @orderby);
    PRINT @sql;
  ```

  Output:

  ```
    SELECT * FROM dbo.table  ORDER BY col1
  ```
- Not using the N prefix when concatenating Unicode string literals > 4000 characters ([example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=52cbf1da8a7a8a9d5919481b0649fe58)):

  ```
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '';

    SET @sql = @sql + '... literally 4001 characters ...';
  ```

  The output here (as shown in the example) will be truncated at 4,000 characters. However if you define your strings properly, this won't happen:

  ```
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'';

    SET @sql = @sql + N'... literally 4001 characters ...';
  ```

These things can be hard to spot in overly complex dynamic SQL generation, so it's never a bad idea to simplify and try any way you can to divide & conquer the major components in the eventual string. Based on the repro you attempted I would almost certainly guess it is the "variable declared too short" symptom. Safest is to ensure every input to a dynamic SQL string should be declared as `nvarchar(max)`; no real good reason to use anything else except for entity names which are constrained by metadata anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the tip of putting it into an XML string. I will take a swing at that and see what it does, but I'd still like to know why PRINT(...) is dropping chunks of the string. I've provided a working example which demonstrates it pretty flagrantly.

Comment: @Will Your "working" example is tragically flawed: you're truncating the string yourself via `nvarchar(100)`.

Comment: I will accept this as the best approach, but the problem I think is that LEN(@sql) is returning not the full length of the string. LEN(@sql) is returning 5730 while DATALENGTH(@sql) is returning 11460. So because of that, the problem is in the print loop getting bad bounds.

Comment: Nope. `LEN()` measures number of characters, so it sounds like your string is 5,730 characters long. `DATALENGTH()` returns number of bytes which, for Unicode strings, is 2 bytes or every character. 5,730 * 2 = 11,460. If you expect your string to be longer than 5,730 characters, there is a reason for that, but we can't speculate because we can't see how you're building it.

Comment: Then there's definitely something wrong because when I copy-paste the text over into Notepad++, NP++ says the total length is 8508 over 226 lines. And I know that isn't helpful to you because I still haven't shown how the string is being built yet, and the reason for that is because I am currently sanitizing it - I'm not super comfortable just posting large chunks of my employers SQL code on the internet :-/

Comment: @Will Copy and paste _from where_? Also I don't know exactly how Notepad++ measures the length of a string and whether you should expect it to match what SQL Server thinks. But I don't know why we're so hyper-focused on the length. You should be focused on the parts of the string that somehow go missing (Notepad++ isn't going to help with that, unless Notepad++ actually _shows you characters_ that SSMS doesn't). And I'll say it again: the problem is 99.999% in the way you're building the string. You haven't found some bug in PRINT that nobody else has come across in two decades.

Comment: @Will if you can't reproduce with anything but "employers SQL code" then that just further demonstrates that the problem is with something in "employers SQL code."

Comment: Copy and paste from SQL Server Studio. And I think the problem is how I formatted it. I think perhaps that LEN(...) does not count TAB characters, and there are a lot of tab characters to make it more human-readable.

Nope, that's not it either, since LEN(A whole bunch of tabs) returns the number of tabs.

Comment: `LEN()` definitely counts TAB characters (`char(9)`), but not _trailing_ spaces. This is [very easy to prove](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=179d444df5b16ab5d999f7a3d651c491) but you could always try generating the string _without_ any TAB characters. If you don't change anything else, I bet you still have the same problem, because a bunch of TAB characters can't be the cause. Also I don't quite know what `from SQL Server Studio` means. From the query window? Grid results? Text results? And again, does Notepad++ actually _show you characters_ you can't see in SSMS?

Comment: @Will I'm really trying to be patient and provide help here but it's kind of useless and frustrating if we can't see how you're building the string. Please don't reply until you can reproduce on something that isn't top secret.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/dLqvSV14

Comment: @Will It works fine [if I put an `N` prefix in front of all my string literals](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c2946f7a42d9ae0176ccddf47a855192), like I should (most importantly the ones that are > 4000 characters, though why you have a single string literal that big I couldn't possibly imagine). You are creating an `nvarchar` variable, you should always use the `N` prefix on all string literals.

Comment: That's a good thing to know. Thank you.

Comment: @Will Probably would have been spotted if you _started_ with some clue about how you were defining and building `@sql`. I wasn't asking for that because I didn't believe you or wanted to steal proprietary company code, but I knew you hadn't stumbled across some new bug in `PRINT`. :-)

Comment: I didn't think you were (trying to steal info, that is). It's just something I'm not comfortable with under any circumstances, sharing something that's not mine.

Comment: `SELECT CAST('' AS xml).query('sql:variable("@sql")')` requires no escaping

Comment: @Charlieface Not what I'm seeing? Tried [in SSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cni1H.png) and in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=683b35efb8e51879d5c75abe9c3d1663).

Comment: Sorry meant to say that it's valid XML without requiring manual escaping to create it as that would happen automatically. Yes it would show up in SSMS with XML escaped characters, don't think you can get around that.